# What is DNA-cellulose chromatography?

Tags: chromatography

I am going through a paper where they have done DNA-cellulose chromatography to study the interaction between protein and DNA. They are adding the protein to the column and eluting with high salt concentration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DNA-cellulose chromatography is used to purify proteins that bind DNA ([Potuzak and Dean 1978](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0014579378801653), [Abdullah et al., 1985](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021967301954767)).

The idea behind it is quite simple: you attach DNA to a cellulose matrix and keep conditions so that the DNA does not dissociate from the cellulose. This stationary phase is then used as a bait for DNA-binding proteins from the mobile phase. The purified DNA-binding proteins can subsequently be dissociated from the column with high salt concentrations.

The method was (as far as I know) first described by [Litnam (1968)](http://www.jbc.org/content/243/23/6222.full.pdf) who used it to extract a DNA polymerase from *Micrococcus luteus*.